# How do I make a C# DataView column invisible?

Tags: c#, dataview

How do I make a C# DataView column invisible? I thought it would be similar to ReadOnly but the following doesn't work because there is no "visible" property.

```
foreach(DataColumn c in myDataView.Table.Columns)
{
    if(visiblecolumns.Contains(c.ColumnName))
    {
        c.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        c.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383893%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

```
customersDataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

UPDATED

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Title,FirstName,LastName FROM
Employees",conn);
da.Fill(ds_orig);
ds_copy = ds_orig.Copy();
dt = ds_copy.Tables[0];
dt.Columns.Remove("Title");
dv = new DataView(dt);
```

Comment: something like: "myDataView.Columns[0].Visible = false;"

Comment: But a DataGridView is not the same as a DataView object (?)

Comment: Hmmm... I assumed you were talking about a datagridview.  A dataview is only a view on a datatable and holds only that plus the
sortorder and the rowfilter.  You could remove columns from the datatable... see updated code above.